# Jquery Alert box not showing

Tags: jquery

Jquery alert box not showing only for empty name, and not showing for father name, email etc. 
When I click on the submit button, it says, "please enter name", even when the father name field or email field is empty.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <link href="style/bootstrap-3.3.7.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css " />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript ">
        var limit = 10;
        var Name;
        var FatherName;
        var CellNo;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                $('#txtName').val();
                if (name == "") {
                    alert("please enter the name");
                    return  ;
                }
            });

                $('#txtFatherName').val();
                if (FatherName == "") {
                    alert("please enter ur father name");
                    return;
                }
                $('#txtEmail').val();
                if (Email == "") {
                    alert("please enter email");
                    return;
                }
                $('#txtAddress').val();
                if (Address == "") {
                    alert("please enter email");
                    return;
                }
                $('#txtCellNo').val();
                if (CellNo == "") {
                    alert("please enter email");
                    return;
                }

        });

</script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="personalInfo">
            <div>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Personal Information</h1>

                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">Name :</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="txtName" class="cls1" name="txtName" size="20" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">Father Name :</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="txtFatherName" class="cls1" name="txtFatherName" size="20" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

            </div>
            <div class=" row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">Email:</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" id="txtEmail " class="cls1" name="txtEmail" size="20" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">Address</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="txtAddress" class="cls1" name="txtAddress" size="20" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">Cell No:</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" id="txtCellNo" class="cls1" name="txtCellNo" size="20" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div class=" row">
                    <div class=" col-sm-2 text-right"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, you're loading bootstrap css and jQuery twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's to get you started.

Based on your example

```
$('#txtName').val();
if (name == "") {
  alert("please enter the name");
  return  ;
}
```

"name" is not defined. The check is actually not doing anything.

Please note: This example does not check if the person has removed something that has previously been entered.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var limit = 10;
  
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var Name = $('#txtName').val();
    var FatherName = $('#txtFatherName').val();
    var CellNo = $('#txtCellNo').val();
    var Email = $('#txtEmail').val();
    var Address = $('#txtAddress').val();
    
    if (Name == "") {
      alert("please enter the name");
      return  ;
    } else if (FatherName == "") {
      alert("please enter ur father name");
      return;
    } else if (Email == "") {
      alert("please enter email");
      return;
    } else if (Address == "") {
      alert("please enter address");
      return;
    } else if (CellNo == "") {
      alert("please enter cell");
      return;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div id="personalInfo">
    <div>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Personal Information</h1>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">Name :</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" id="txtName" class="cls1" name="txtName" size="20" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">Father Name :</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" id="txtFatherName" class="cls1" name="txtFatherName" size="20" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class=" row">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">Email:</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" id="txtEmail " class="cls1" name="txtEmail" size="20" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">Address</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" id="txtAddress" class="cls1" name="txtAddress" size="20" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">Cell No:</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" id="txtCellNo" class="cls1" name="txtCellNo" size="20" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />

      <div class=" row">
        <div class=" col-sm-2 text-right"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```